# File system permissions lost or unseen

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

Ok, I have an apparent WTF question here.

I log as root, I run:

```
# ls /var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite/logs/ -l
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 gitolite3 gitolite3 5570 Aug  2 21:00 gitolite-2013-08.log
```

No problem? I log in as gitolite3, run the same thing again:

```
# su gitolite3
$ ls /var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite/logs/ -l
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? gitolite-2013-08.log
```

What is going on? There are also errors elsewhere saying that log cannot be accessed. FS is EXT4. OS is Centos6.4. Before, I had to change the uid and gid of gitolite3 to let suexec run commands under that user and group, and consequently I had to chown -R gitolite3:gitolite3 that folder tree again. Fsck doesn't let me, the FS is already mounted.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the user gitolite3 doesn't have the permissions to do execute on the directory, so it can't read the inodes (where the permissions are stored). You have to grant gitolite3 execute on the directory you are in with something like this:

chmod o+x /var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite/logs

Comment: Yup! That tricked it. You learn something every day.